How to tell if cost function (a sum of quadratics) is convex?
I have a mixed integer nonlinear programming optimization problem with the following characteristics:

All the constraints are linear
The cost function (which I want to minimize) is a sum of quadratics, like:
$\operatorname{Cost} = \sum_{j}\left(\sum_{i}^{}x_{i,j}-c_{j}\right)^{2}$

where $X$ is the matrix of variables I am solving for, and $C$ is a matrix of constant values input to the problem.
I want to know if this problem is unimodal. That is, if the problem is feasible, it has only one extremum, which is necessarily the global extremum.
I am not a mathematician, but I did some reading, and I think I understood that I can answer this if I compute the eigenvalues of the Hessian matrix of the cost function, which is itself computed based on the second partial derivatives of the cost function. I had calculus, differential equations, and linear algebra as an undergraduate many years ago, but I think this problem would take me about a week to solve (if I even got it right with no mistakes).
I am asking: is there any easier way to know if my cost function is unimodal (or convex, which I guess is the same thing)?
Followup / Example:
I did some calculations on a few simple examples having the form of my cost function.  E.g.,
$$
\frac{\partial ^2\left(((\text{x1}+\text{x2}+\text{x3}+\text{x4})-2)^2+((\text{x1}+\text{x2})-5)^2+((\text{x1}+\text{x5}+\text{x6})-17)^2\right)}{\partial
\{\text{x1},\text{x2},\text{x3},\text{x4},\text{x5},\text{x6}\}^2}
$$
The resulting Hessian matrix always seemed to by symmetric with positive valued elements.  E.g., for the above,
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cccccc}
6 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\ 
4 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\ 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}\right)
$$
... for which the eigenvalues are all positive:
$λ_1≈11.7902$
$λ_2≈4.79459$
$λ_3≈1.4152$
$λ_4≈0$
$λ_5≈0$
$λ_6≈0$
Am I correct in understanding that, at least for this example, that the Hessian matrix is positive definite and that, therefore, the cost function is strictly convex?
This is the outcome for every simple example I've tried.  How can I be sure it is true generally?
Note: in this example, the same variable appears in multiple sums in the cost function.  That actually won't be the case in my real cost function, if it matters.  I was trying to create a "worst case" example.

It is convex because $y\to y^2$ is convex and your cost is a sum of such where $y$ are some affine transformations of $x$. See Second-Order Cone Programming (SOCP).

@MichalAdamaszek Are you saying that a sum of convex functions is also going to be convex?

A sum of convex functions is convex.
